# $\{r\in{R} \ : \ r\mathfrak{a}\subseteq{\mathfrak{a}}\}$ is a subring maximal with respect to having $\mathfrak{a}$ as an ideal

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R$ be an associative ring and $\mathfrak{a}$ a right ideal.

Let $R'=\{r\in{R} \ : \ r\mathfrak{a}\subseteq{\mathfrak{a}}\}$, and show that $R'$ is a maximal subring such that $\mathfrak{a}$ is a ideal in $R'$.

Let $S$ be a subring such that $\mathfrak{a}$ is a ideal of $S$, and let $x\in{S}$. Then $x\mathfrak{a}\subseteq{\mathfrak{a}}$ ($\mathfrak{a}$ is ideal in $S$) therefore $x\in{R'}$. So $S\subseteq{R'}$, and therefore $R'$ is a ring maximal such that $\mathfrak{a}$ is ideal in $R'$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Your argument does show that every subring that has $\mathfrak a$ as an ideal is contained in $R'$. However, you haven't proved (here) that $R'$ is actually a subring of $R$.

Comment: @KarlKronenfeld; why ?, thanks

Comment: @user126033 One way would be to describe why $R'$ is an additive subgroup of $R$, and that it's multiplicatively closed. Additionally it would be good to point out that it shares identity with $R$.

Answer (score 1):

To show this is a genuine subring:
Firstly, if $s,t \in R'$ then for any $a \in \mathfrak a$ we have $sa, ta \in \mathfrak a$, and since $\mathfrak a$ is an ideal it follows that $sa + ta = (s+t)a \in \mathfrak a$.

Clearly zero and $1$ (if your ring has an identity) satisfy $0\mathfrak a \subseteq \mathfrak a$ and $1\mathfrak a \subseteq \mathfrak a$.

Lastly, it is clearly closed under multiplication — if $s,t \in R'$ then $s(t\mathfrak a) \subseteq s \mathfrak a \subseteq \mathfrak a$.

Now maximality. Suppose $R''$ is a subring of $R$ such that $R' \subsetneq R''$. Then take $t \in R'' \setminus R'$. Then $t \mathfrak a \not\subset \mathfrak a$. Hence $\mathfrak a$ is not an ideal of $R''$.